# How can I copy and compare a string?

Tags: serial, string

I have the following code (I realise String isn't very efficient, but this sketch doesn't have to be)

debugOutput gets called every loop, but I only want to spam the serial bus (to debug) if the status changes.

However, it runs once, despite changes to the pins being made.

```
String prevState = "";
void debugOutput() {
  String s = "";
  //s = s + digitalRead(6) ? "1" : "0";
  //s = s + digitalRead(5) ? "1" : "0";
  s = s + digitalRead(4) ? "1" : "0";
  s = s + digitalRead(3) ? "1" : "0";
  s = s + digitalRead(2) ? "1" : "0";
  if(!prevState.equals(s)) {
    Serial.println("State Change: "+s);
    //strcpy(s, prevState);
    prevState = s;
  }
}
```

My suspicion is it was because of the pointers being the same, but I declare a new string every time this function runs. Just in case, I tried to swap this to strcpy, which isn't valid since I'm using String instead of character arrays.

What can I do, I'm really confused.

This is the Serial output, btw

`State Change: 1` So it's clear to me that my string appending isn't even working as expected.

Comment: Why are you using a String for this?  Just save the pin states and compare them and if any have changed send a message.  Take out the intermediate step of creating a String from that data and compare the data directly.

Comment: Why using a String? Anyway making a copy si as simple as `prevState = s;` And check for inequality is simply `prevState != s`.

Comment: This was intended to be quick and dirty debug code that wouldn't be in the final thing, I was attempting to do what I thought was easy and quick for me at the time, but when you need to start debugging your debugging code, you start to get frustrated.

Comment: I've added an edit as I realized I missed including what my serial output was.

Comment: Yeah, operator priority is kinda need to know (or you have to use paretheses). Even  +=  operator would let you avoid stuff like adding result of digital with s and then use it as bool value for ?:  :D

Comment: Operator Priority? God damn it, I assumed that the types disambiguate it (coming from Java, C#) would prevent that from happening, now I feel really foolish.

Comment: The string class can handle  String+int, and obviously it can be also implicitly casted to the bool value (which is really surprising and quite dangerous operator in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this thing called "operator precedence" that defines the hierarchy of operators.

The `?:` will be calculated after the `+`. That's why

```
s = s + digitalRead(2) ? "1" : "0";
```

actually means

```
s = (s + digitalRead(2)) ? "1" : "0";
```

But you want

```
s = s + (digitalRead(2) ? "1" : "0");
```

Comment: To make this a more useful answer, you should really mention how the types are ignored / coerced. I've awarded you the answer regardless though. I was aware of operator precedence, but not how it interacted with the types under C.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why string appending using + was failing, but changing it from

`s = s + digitalRead(2) ? "1" : "0";`

to

`s += digitalRead(2) ? "1" : "0";`

fixed my issue.

Comment: I won't be accepting this as the answer, even though that it is AN answer, in order to award the answer points to someone that explains what was wrong.

Comment: first of all you shouldn't use String for this. you can store numbers, compare numbers, print numbers. digitalRead returns a number